# interpretation of the code

Tags: sas, proc

I am completely new to sas. Can you please help me to interpret this code:

```
PROC MEANS DATA=debt;

   VAR debt_liab;

   OUTPUT OUT=median MEDIAN=med_d_l;

RUN;
```

Is the interpretation as follows: from the data set - "debt" create a variable "med_d_l" that is a median of the "debt_liab" variable across the whole sample. Am I right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.
You left out that the new variable `med_d_l` will be in the new dataset named `median`.